# How to avoid a stack overflow with State monad

Tags: scala, scalaz

I encountered a stack overflow using scalaz State Monad.

Here is the culprit `iterator.toList.traverseS_(collectOne)`. the iterator contains a lot of elements (10M)

- Q1 : `iterator.toList` force the evaluation, that I want avoid. But I need a list to call traverseS_
- Q2 : Any idea for a workaround to avoid the stack overflow ?

I think cutting the process in sublists but I have to combine the State at the end…
The question is now how to transform Iterable[State] -> State

Comment: There is also a `traverseSTrampoline` in scalaz which could help here. (Needs `G[_]` to be an `Applicative` though in `collectOne: A ⇒ State[S, G[B]]`.)

Comment: If you wrap your values in `Free`, you effectively move the `flatMap` calls from consuming stack to consuming heap. See http://termsandtruthconditions.com/blog/2013/03/16/free-monad/

Comment: @Debilski in my case, G = Unit

Comment: Maybe you can use this trick to get from `A ⇒ State[S, Unit]` to `A ⇒ State[S, Nil.type]` (which is an `Applicative`): `collectOne andThen (_.map(_ => Nil))`. Not really sure this works in all cases, though.

Comment: Hurra, it works ! just add an _ : `collectOne _ andThen (_.map(_ => Nil))`. Any idea for Q1 ? (iterator comes from a file that I don't want to have entirely in memory)

Comment: Would operating on streams as opposed to lists work? You could do `iterator.toStream` first, then it would evaluate lazily...